# Chrome, Firefox and Safari extension authenticate a computer

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, safari-extension

I am desining a Chrome, FF and Safari extension. I wnt someone to be able to let spmeone install the plugin on no more than 5 computers. So, basically one account on my site can 'authorise' up to 5 computers. And deauthorise them as well. Are there any ways to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I don't think you can identify/authenticate at the computer level. But what you can do is identify/authenticate at the browser level. Just use the browser's local storage to:

1. Generate a unique ID at the first launch
2. Tie it to an account manager online
3. Store the ID locally
4. Use the tied ID for further uses of your extension

It can be hackable, but it requires to go edit the browser's local storage manually. 99.95% of your users won't be able to do that.

Also, I think you would have to inform the user properly about this.